# Flex (toFixed) numbers formatting

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have the following code to retrieve the result.

```
var _label:Number = (data.ask - data.bid) * 10000;
this.text = String(_label.toFixed(0));
```

I would like to know what to add in order to retrieve the first 2 numbers from the left only for the results. e.g.,:

1234756.21354 > 12

75484.014 > 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.substr()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr%28%29), [.slice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#slice%28%29) or [.substring()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring%28%29) methods:

```
this.text = String(_label.toFixed(0)).substr(0,2);
//this.text = String(_label.toFixed(0)).slice(0,2);
//this.text = String(_label.toFixed(0)).substring(0,2);
```

For adding `.`(dot) between, try this:

```
var numstr:String = String(_label.toFixed(0)).substr(0,2);
this.text = Number(numstr)/10 + "";
```

Comment: Great thank you: is there any way to display it in this format:
1234756.21354 > 1.2